# Scroll frameset/frame on iPad Safari

Tags: html, ios, ipad, safari, frame

I have a  with 3 frames. Now the height of the midddle  is dynamic i.e. depends on the content..
I have an issue with this on the iPad. i.e. if the height for this middle increases, the footer frame appears partially or in some cases completely hidden..Also I cannot scroll through the same. Indirectly speaking, the visible area on the iPad remains fixed as per the screen height and we cannot scroll through any hidden content..

Before you say, I know frameset/frame is outdated, But as of now, I have limited choice...And I think evcen iframes have an issue on iPad.

Please help me. Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two fingers to scroll a frame or iframe in iOS Safari, but it's a nasty, hard to discover user interface. Frames are going to be effectively unusable for users in iOS.

Comment: Unfortunately, i already tried that and am not able to scroll..seems to be a known ipad issue with ios 4.3